# I can't run my Nunit test in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit

In my asp.net core project (vs 2017), I want to run my test method but ı click the 'run all' in test explorer, I get "**Last Test Run Not Run** (Total Run Time 'bla bla')" response in **test explorer** console. I have my Nunit NuGet package already downloaded. I think ı have some missing testing configurations for testing in asp.net core in my startup class or somewhere else or some missing NuGet packages :/ Thx in advance to everyone.

Here is my test class:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Software_Testing.Controllers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Software_Testing.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class NunitTest
    {
        GuessService GuessService = new GuessService();

        [Test]
        public void GuessTest()
        {
            var result = GuessService.Guess("This is a test description with less then 20 words.");
            Assert.AreEqual("1-3 Gün", result);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **"Guess service"** class which has **guess** method I'm using in my test method **(guessTest)**:

```
    public class GuessService
    {
        public string Guess(string desc)
        {
            string s = desc;            //açıklamadaki kelime sayısına göre süre tahminlemesi yapılır...
            string[] coutn = s.ToString().Split(' ');
            int i = coutn.Count();
            if (i <= 20)
            {
                return "1-3 Gün";
            }
            else if (20 < i && i <= 40)
            {
                return "3-5 Gün";
            }
            else if (40 < i)
            {
                return "5-7 Gün";
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

And here is my ss of test explorer:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers to this question? [Tests not running in Test Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23363073)

Comment: yes but most of them was about to old versions of vs

Answer (score 1):

I got my solution on my own :/ I' haven't added this nugget packages below:
***NUnit3TestAdapter**
***Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk**