# Can't run a simple Unit Test #Cs #VS19 #MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, mstest

I'm new in unit test and I'm trying to run a simple test but after push the "run test" button it's load then nothing

What's wrong ????!!

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using TestNinja.Fundamentals;

namespace TestNinga.UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ReservationTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CanBeCancelledBy_UserIsAdmin_ReturnTrue()
        {

            var reservation = new Reservation();

            var result = reservation.CanBeCancelledBy(new User { IsAdmin = true });

            Assert.IsTrue(result); 
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the output window, if there are any more details.

Comment: Hope the following reference could be helpful: [Tests not running in Test Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363073/tests-not-running-in-test-explorer)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like nothing is wrong. Sometimes this happens also to me and sometimes I fix it by closing the `VS`, deleting the `bin` & `obj` folders, opening the `VS`, and cleaning the solution. One time I also noted out that the process runs in the background and stuck and as a result, the tests didn't run, so I killed the process, and then it started working.

If it won't help you always can see what is the error you get and share more information.

To see the error you should open the `Output` pane and in the `Show output from:` box, you should choose the tests option.

Comment: after delete bin & obj and open the output window this the result of running a test :

---------- Starting test run ----------
No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=TestNinga.UnitTests.ReservationTests.CanBeCancelledBy_UserIsAdmin_ReturnTrue` in C:\Users\try\Desktop\TestNinja\TestNinga.UnitTests\bin\Debug\TestNinga.UnitTests.dll
========== Test run finished: 0 Tests run in 910.4 ms (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) ==========

Comment: Good call. When I went to the `Output` pane and selected `Show output from: Tests`, I was able to see a Cleanup function throwing a null reference error :0

Answer (score 2):

I find the isssue , I just update/add this package in my test solution :

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
- MSTest.TestAdapter
- MSTest.TestFramework

Comment: Consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).